# Android Pass List<HashMap<String, String>> to new activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have defined a List in my main class where I am loading data from KSoap response:

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> POIs= new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

I add entry to the Listusing the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < response1.getPropertyCount(); i++) {            
  SoapObject response2 = (SoapObject) response1.getProperty(i);
  HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();                  
  map.put("ID",response2.getProperty("CID").toString());
  map.put("Distance",response2.getProperty("distance").toString());
  map.put("SubLocality",response2.getProperty("SubLocality1").toString());
  POIs.add(map);
}
```

I like to know how I put the list POIs to an intent?

Answer (score 1):

Access your `List` using the main class' object. Simple as that.

Comment: Create a getter method in your main class. In your activity,make object of that class and access the `List`.

Comment: If you even need a code for this, you need to go back to Java basics.

Comment: @tai.tran2008 not unless it is actually a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I used Bundle.putSerializable to pass the List since the it is not large (only about 10 items).